# Create new dataframe from selected information from another datama

Tags: java, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- lat: Long (nullable = true)
 |-- lon: Long (nullable = true)
 |-- nds: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ref: long (nullable = true)
 |-- members: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ref: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- role: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to create a new dataframe `res` where I select specific data from the column `tags`. I need the `values` from `key=place` and `key=population`. The new dataframe should have the following schema:

```
val schema = StructType(
               Array(
                 StructField("place", StringType),
                 StructField("population", LongType)
               )
             )
```

I have litteraly no idea how I to do this. I tried to replicate the first dataframe and then select the columns, but that didnt work.

Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly apply desired key on column of type map to extract value, then cast and rename column as you wish as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.LongType

val result = dataframe.select(
  col("tags")("place").as("place"),
  col("tags")("population").cast(LongType).as("population")
)
```

With the following `tags` column:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|tags                                            |
+------------------------------------------------+
|{place -> A, population -> 32, another_key -> X}|
|{place -> B, population -> 64, another_key -> Y}|
+------------------------------------------------+
```

You get the following result:

```
+-----+----------+
|place|population|
+-----+----------+
|A    |32        |
|B    |64        |
+-----+----------+
```

Having the following schema:

```
root
 |-- place: string (nullable = true)
 |-- population: long (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets call your original dataframe `df`. You can extract the information you want like this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sql.col

val data = df
  .select("tags")
  .where(
    df("tags")("key") isin (List("place", "population"): _*)
  )
  .select(
    col("tags")("value")
  )
  .collect()
  .toList
```

This will give you a `List[Row]` which can be converted to another dataframe with your schema

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList

sparkSession.createDataFrame(seqAsJavaList[Row](data), schema)
```

Comment: I tried this method. New dataframe is created with the desired schema. However, the new dataframe is empty. I think that I do the convertion wrong. What I did:

val output = spark.createDataFrame(seqAsJavaList[Row](data), schema)

Answer (score 0):

Given the following simplified input:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  (1L, Map("place" -> "home", "population" -> "1", "name" -> "foo")),
  (2L, Map("place" -> "home", "population" -> "4", "name" -> "foo")),
  (3L, Map("population" -> "3")),
  (4L, Map.empty[String, String])
).toDF("id", "tags")
```

You want to select the values using methods `map_filter` to filter the map to only contain the key you want, then call `map_values` to get those entries. `map_values` returns an array, so you need to use `explode_outer` to flatten the data. We use `explode_outer` here because you might have entries which have neither place nor population, or only one of the two. Once the data is in a form we can easily work with, we just select the fields we want in the desired structure.

I've left the `id` column in so when you run the example you can see that we don't drop entries with missing data.

```scala
val r = df.select(
    col("id"),
    explode_outer(map_values(map_filter(col("tags"), (k,_) => k === "place"))) as "place",
    map_values(map_filter(col("tags"), (k,_) => k === "population")) as "population"
  ).withColumn("population", explode_outer(col("population")))
  .select(
    col("id"),
    array(
      struct(
        col("place"),
        col("population") cast LongType as "population"
      ) as "place_and_population"
    ) as "data"
  )
```

Gives:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- data: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- place: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- population: long (nullable = true)

+---+--------------+
| id|          data|
+---+--------------+
|  1|   [{home, 1}]|
|  2|   [{home, 4}]|
|  3|   [{null, 3}]|
|  4|[{null, null}]|
+---+--------------+
```